# Primefaces' messed up look and feel in IE7

Tags: html, css, primefaces, internet-explorer-7

I am using Primefaces version 3.2 for my application and it is working perfect on all other browsers. but when I open it on IE7, all the look and feel is terribly messed up. 
Can anyone tell me what can be done to get over this?
I am attaching screenshot for reference.

[image]

```
 <p:panel id="p_QDEF0061" style="height:auto;">
<div style="width:100%;height:auto;border:none;margin:0px 2px 0px 2px;" id="QDEF0061_content">
<p:dataTable value="#{reportRunManager.getResult('QDEF0061', '1')}" var="row" id="QDEF0061table" rows="20" styleClass="report" style="width:1216px;" rowClasses="odd-row, even-row" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowIndexVar="index">
  <p:column style="width:91px !important;" colspan="1">
    <f:facet name="header" styleClass="rHdr">
      <div style="text-align:left;">
        <h:outputText value="Completed by" />
      </div>
    </f:facet>
    <div style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:91px">
      <h:outputText value="#{row.get('crc_review_user_login')}" escape="false" />
    </div>
  </p:column>
  <p:column style="width:93px !important;" colspan="1">
    <f:facet name="header" styleClass="rHdr">
      <div style="text-align:left;">
        <h:outputText value="Completed On" />
      </div>
    </f:facet>
    <div style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:93px">
      <h:outputText value="#{row.get('crc_review_complete_date')}" escape="false">
        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
      </h:outputText>
    </div>
  </p:column>
  <p:column style="width:93px !important;" colspan="1">
    <f:facet name="header" styleClass="rHdr">
      <div style="text-align:left;">
        <h:outputText value="Date of Service" />
      </div>
    </f:facet>
    <div style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:93px">
      <h:outputText value="#{row.get('crc_review_svc_date')}" escape="false">
        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
      </h:outputText>
    </div>
  </p:column>
  <p:column style="width:79px !important;" colspan="1">
    <f:facet name="header" styleClass="rHdr">
      <div style="text-align:left;">
        <h:outputText value="Post Date" />
      </div>
    </f:facet>
    <div style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:79px">
      <h:outputText value="#{row.get('crc_review_post_date')}" escape="false">
        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
      </h:outputText>
    </div>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</div>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: Can you post some code? It would help if your example was small and easily reproduced. If you look at your alignment it looks like the scroll-bar calculation is off.

Comment: @DanielChapman Chapman  I have added some of my xhtml code in my question.

Comment: What happens if you dump your width and height requirements on the table?

Comment: @DanielChapman I can avoid the vertical scrollbar but some table's have very large number of columns i.e around 15-20, so horizontal scroll is still essential.

Comment: This is very likely a CSS issue. You use inline CSS and a separate style sheet. Please post the relevant parts of the CSS so we can see what IE is doing to your CSS. ;-)

Comment: @User_0001 we also need what IE is rendering. The JSF doesn't show the output.

Comment: @DanielChapman:: hi I just removed Height and width restrictions from body element of html and this problem was gone.. thanx for the hint in your 2nd comment :)

Comment: By the way, PrimeFaces 3.5 has dropped support for IE7.